# Mock Paramiko file properties for unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, paramiko

I have the below function which takes a sftp file (from a paramiko connection paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient) at 0x... and a datetime object, compares them and returns True if the former is greater than the latter.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def is_recently_modified_file_sftp(file, since_when):
    modif_time = dt.fromtimestamp(file.st_mtime)
    return modif_time >= since_when
```

However, I'm struggling to create a unit test for this. How could I mock the paramiko file?

Comment: Just create a dict with the `st_mtime` property as mock file

Comment: @slideshowp2 how could I do that? Could you please provide an example?